# When to Use Rows or Semantic tag(s) in a Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, frontend

If I have a two column layout

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 push-4 columns">main content</div>
  <div class="large-4 pull-8 columns">side nav</div>
</div>
```

If i have the below content in the `main content` div:

### Introduction Text

Memorial Day is a US federal holiday wherein the men and women who died while serving in the United States Armed Forces are remembered.[1] The holiday, which is celebrated every year on the final Monday of May,[2] was formerly known as Decoration Day and originated after the American Civil War to commemorate the Union and Confederate soldiers who died in the Civil War. By the 20th century, Memorial Day had been extended to honor all Americans who have died while in the military service. It typically marks the start of the summer vacation season, while Labor Day marks its end.

### History of the holiday

The practice of decorating soldiers' graves with flowers is an ancient custom.[5] Soldiers' graves were decorated in the U.S. before[6] and during the American Civil War. A claim was made in 1906 that the first Civil War soldier's grave ever decorated was in Warrenton, Virginia, on June 3, 1861, implying the first Memorial Day occurred there.[7] Though not for Union soldiers, there is authentic documentation that women in Savannah, Georgia, decorated Confederate soldiers' graves in 1862.[8] In 1863, the cemetery dedication at Gettysburg, Pennsylvania, was a ceremony of commemoration at the graves of dead soldiers. Local historians in Boalsburg, Pennsylvania, claim that ladies there decorated soldiers' graves on July 4, 1864.[9] As a result, Boalsburg promotes itself as the birthplace of Memorial Day.

---

Should the **Introduction Text** and the **History of the holiday** section each be in it's own row and column or should I be using the semantic tags? See below example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 push-4 columns">    
     <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">Introduction text and next paragraph</div>
     </div>

     <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">History of the holiday and next paragraph</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 push-4 columns">    
     <section>
       <div>Introduction text and next paragraph</div>
     </section>

     <section>
       <div>History of the holiday and next paragraph</div>
     </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use <h1> and <p>?

Comment: I would use <h1> and <p> but I'm more concerned with which tags to wrap those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec a section might be a little more semantic in this situation as you could want each section listed as a part of the document's outline. However, if you're just wrapping them for styling, a div is a better choice.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-section-element):

> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s outline.